# AWS Amplify Graphql Query Secondary Index Value And Then Sort By UpdatedAt

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify

**Use Case:**

I am trying to create a graphql secondary index where I can sort the direction of the items by `updatedAt`, but also query for one `status`. For example *"get all the candidate's applications where `candidateStatus === "Applied"`, and have them ordered by `updatedAt`".*

**Graphql Code:**

```
type Application
  @model
  @auth(...) {
  id: ID!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
  candidateStatus: String
  candidateID: ID
    @index(
      name: "byCandidateApplications"
      queryField: "byCandidateApplications"
      sortKeyFields: ["updatedAt", "candidateStatus"]
    )
}
```

**Limitations:**

When testing with AppSync, the `updatedAt` is required in the `eq` for it to work.

```
query MyQuery {
  byCandidateApplications(
  candidateID: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  updatedAtCandidateStatus: { eq: {candidateStatus: "Applied" } }, sortDirection: ASC) {
    nextToken
    items {
      updatedAt
    }
  }
}
```

**Error Message:**

`"message": "When providing argument 'updatedAtCandidateStatus.$operation.candidateStatus' you must also provide 'updatedAtCandidateStatus.$operation.updatedAt'."`

**Saying No To Filters:**

I cannot use filters in this example, as I'll have to set a search limit of 15. Filters only work after the return of 15 items, and thus do not offer a solution that will return all `Applied` applications. (one `Applied` application could be the 16th and thus missed).